# compiler error in c++ header, "was not declared in this scope"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When i try to compile my header file, the compiler tells me " 'map' was not declared in this scope" ( the line below `public:` ). Why?

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#ifndef TILEMAP_H
#define TILEMAP_H

class TileMap{

public:
    std::vector<std::vector<sf::Vector2i>> map;
    std::ifstream file;
    TileMap(std::string name);
    sf::Sprite tiles;
    sf::Texture tileTexture;
    void update();
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow* window);



};

#endif
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have an space between two ">" otherwise compiler will be confused it with ">>" operator. So do like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<sf::Vector2i> > map;
```

That's why it's always a good idea to typedef STL types if you want to use one inside another. So it's better to do like this:

```
typedef std::vector<sf::Vector2i> Mytype;
std::vector<Mytype> map;
```

This way you won't get compilation error because of forgetting to put space in between of ">".

Comment: Note: The `>>`/`> >` is a problem in C++98/03 but no longer in C++11.